# Writing the output of a python script in a Hadoop table using Hive's TRANSFORM command

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I need to use a python script within a Hive query in order to transform data from a Hadoop table (mytable1) and writing the output of the transformation into another table (mytable2), because the data I need is in a complicated JSON. The transformation should take 1 line from mytable1 and write 360 lines in mytable2.

In order to do so I was advised to use the TRANSFORM command of Hive, which allows to call a python script within the query (scripts are below).

My problem is that while the whole things runs, nothing is written in my output table.

I understood that the way this workflow works is: the output of the first subquery is read by the python script from stdin. Then the transformed output is written is stdout (in tab separated format), where it is then read back by Hive. So I've tested independently some elements:

- The sub-query reading mytable1 works well.
- I've also tested the python script, feeding it the output of the sub-query, and it gives the results I want in the expected tab separated format.
- I've tried to execute the query without writing the output into the table, and here I don't get any output, so the problem is probably not related to the table creation.

So my guess is that the output of the python script is not read by Hive. But I don't understand why, as I've used a Hive and Python syntax that has proven to work in a similar case for a colleague of mine.

My Hive query looks like this:

```
ADD FILE parsing_json.py;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable2;
CREATE TABLE mytable2
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\011' 
AS

SELECT TRANSFORM (output_col1,
                  output_col2,
                  output_col3)
                  USING 'parsing_json.py'
AS (input_col1,
    input_col2)
FROM (SELECT input_col1, input_col2 FROM mytable1);
```

With a python script looking like that:

```
import sys
import pandas


def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        var1, var2, var3 = line.split('\t')

        # my output Dataframe has 2 columns
        output = sometransformation(var1, var2, var3)
        print output.to_csv(sep='\t', index=False, header=False),


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of python you are using.
But you can write to Hive from CSV file using OS library. 
Below is the code

```
import os;

output.to_csv('/home/output.csv',sep='\t', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

load_statement = "hive -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/output.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytable2\""

os.system(load_statement);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing `python` in front of your `.py` file in your `SELECT` statement.

try:

```
USING 'python parsing_json.py'
```

instead.

Adding shebang in your .py also works.